# What is a driver program?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I am being asked to create a driver program and skeletal symbol class in flex and bison. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. We are using C as our language. I really don't understand what the driver program does.

Comment: Google says this: http://www.bisondriving.com/dfp

Comment: Then again, it also says this: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds001099

Answer (score 3):

In CS homework, a driver program is generally a module that contains your main method and demonstrates the use of your classes and functions.

Comment: Asking to demonstrate use of classes in a C program is a cruel assignment. Perhaps it's meant to teach the difference between C and C++?